# «Не» или «ни» в стихотворении Анастасии Цветаевой?

Tags: орфография, поэзия, не-или-ни

У Анастасии Цветаевой есть такая строфа:

*Где судьба бы вам жить **не** велела,

В шумном свете иль сельской глуши,

Расточайте без счета и смело

Все сокровища вашей души!*

Отчего Анастасия написала "не велела"? Мне кажется, в данном случае надо писать "ни велела". Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корректорская ошибка. В [других изданиях](http://tsvetaeva.lit-info.ru/tsvetaeva/vospominaniya/cvetaeva-anastasiya/4-glava-3-osen-190) исправлено:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[А потомкам Анастасия Цветаева завещала: «Где судьба бы вам жить ни велела — в блеске бала иль в сельской тиши, расточайте без счёта и смело все сокровища вашей души».](https://russkiymir.ru/publications/151567/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Случай не редкий. Во всех изданиях - искажённый Мандельштам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Найдите временной перескок - стихи иную картинку рисуют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемая Галина, спасибо Вам!          
Я так и думал.      

И отдельное спасибо за комментарий о корректорский ошибке в стихотворении О.М.
Когда-то и меня зацепила эта шороховатость. Но теперь я понял, в чём было дело.

Comment: У Мандельштама - не корректорская! Нет издания - ни одного! - соответствующего оригиналу. Как первый дурак не вдумываясь с рукописи списал, так и закрепилось намертво.

Comment: А у Анастасии, упрямой и недоброй, ошибка её собственная, и править запрещала а-ля Солженицын, - думаю, корректоры устроили бунт на корабле и кинулись к редакторам (чьё слово решающее). Вот те уже охнули: да-а-а, кхм, накладочка-с. Исправлено в посмертных изданиях. Марину А. ненавидела, на вопросы о ней отвечала: мне и о своей судьбе есть что рассказать.